# Can't upload to Arduino Mini via Arduino USB 2 Serial Converter

Tags: serial, arduino-pro-mini, uploading, ftdi, arduino-mini

I bought an Arduino Mini and also an Arduino USB 2 Serial Converter.
While trying to program the Arduino Mini, I get this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

After doing some research I tried many things like changing the settings, serial port, made sure I'm using the right Arduino etcetera.

Some points to consider:

- I tried burning the bootloader using my Arduino Uno.
- Uploading sketches to the Arduino Mini using my Arduino Uno works (so problem is not directly with the Mini).
- I *am* pressing the Reset button before uploading. I also tried hooking a capacitor and the Reset wire directly. No change.

The wiring (I also tried connecting TX of Mini to RX of serial converter, and vice versa):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino USB 2 Serial converter was defect (even though brand new). I bought a cheaper (7 Euro) FTDI to USB and I can now upload.